# OpenCV DNN assertion failed in getMemoryShapes

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, object-detection

I have trained a model using Tensorflow's Object Detection API following their guidance. I have also generated the files for deployment and am attempting to classify an image. OpenCV's DNN file can load the graph using `readNetFromTensorflow` without error however when I attempt to set the input of the network and call `.forward()` it gives the below error. I have searched low and high for a solution to this however I have been unable to find anything to point me in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[INFO] loading model...
[INFO] starting video stream...
[ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (int(numPriors * _numClasses) == inputs[1][1]) in getMemoryShapes, file /home/pi/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/detection_output_layer.cpp, line 202
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "real_time_object_detection.py", line 68, in <module>
    detections = net.forward()
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/detection_output_layer.cpp:202: error: (-215) int(numPriors * _numClasses) == inputs[1][1] in function getMemoryShapes
```

Comment: Please specify what kind of model is trained and what changes in config file have been made. In example this is config for MobileNet-SSD: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config

Answer (score 2):

I've been facing the exact same error. The trick is to transform your `pipeline.config` that you have used for training with this script [tf_text_graph_ssd](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_ssd.py).

```
python3 tf_text_graph_ssd.py \
--input=<path to the frozen inference graph> \
--config=<path to the pipeline.config used for training> \
--output=<output file>
```

then create the network with opencv

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(config=<path to generated file>, model=<path to frozen inference graph>)
```

and infer the network

```
image = cv2.imread('som image file')
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image=image, scalefactor=1.0, size=(300, 300))
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
```

check for the `size=(300, 300)` tuple, this size is from `pipeline.config` file

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 90
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
...
```

also check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55158339/tensorflow-pb-and-pbtxt-files-dont-work-with-opencv-after-retraining-mobilenet) possibly for more information.