# Tensorflow' pb and pbtxt files don't work with OpenCV after retraining MobileNet SSD V1 COCO

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have followed [this](https://3sidedcube.com/guide-retraining-object-detection-models-tensorflow/) tutorial to retrain MobileNet SSD V1 using Tensorflow GPU as described and got 0.5 loss after training using GPU *(below more info about config)* and got `model.ckpt`.

This is the command I used for Training:

`python ../models/research/object_detection/legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=./data/ --pipeline_config_path=./ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config`

And this is the command for freezing (generate pb file):

`python ../models/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path ./ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix ./data/model.ckpt-1407 --output_directory ./data/`

This is the error I get when I use frozen `pb` and `pbtxt`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Object_detection_image.py", line 29, in <module>
    cvOut = cvNet.forward()
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:565: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() == requiredOutputs in function 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v7::DataLayer::getMemoryShapes'
```

This is the `Object_detection_image.py` file I used:

```
import cv2 as cv
import os 
import time 
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
fh = logging.FileHandler('xyz.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)    
logger.addHandler(fh)

cvNet = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'object_detection.pbtxt')
dir_x  = "C:\\Users\\Omen\\Desktop\\LP_dataset\\anno"
for filename in os.listdir(dir_x):
    print(filename)
    if not (filename.endswith(".png") or filename.endswith(".jpg")):
        continue
    print('daz')
    img = cv.imread(os.path.join(dir_x,filename))
    img = cv.resize(img, (300,300))
    #cv.imshow('i',img)
    #cv.waitKey(0)
    img = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    rows = img.shape[0]
    cols = img.shape[1]
    #cvNet.setInput(cv.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(cols,rows), swapRB=True, crop=False))
    cvNet.setInput(cv.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(300, 300), crop=False))
    t0  = time.time()
    cvOut = cvNet.forward()
    print(time.time() - t0)
    for detection in cvOut[0,0,:,:]:
        score = float(detection[2])
        #print(score)
        if score > 0.80:
            left = detection[3] * cols
            top = detection[4] * rows
            right = detection[5] * cols
            bottom = detection[6] * rows
            cv.rectangle(img, (int(left), int(top)), (int(right), int(bottom)), (23, 230, 210), thickness=2)

    cv.imshow('img', img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
```

This is `pbtxt` file *(also I tried the exported pbtxt and generated pbtxt from pb but not working)*:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'licenseplate'
}
```

**Config:**

What is the top-level directory of the model you are using: object_detetion

Have I written custom code: no

OS Platform and Distribution: win10

TensorFlow installed from: binary

TensorFlow GPU version: 1.13.0

CUDA/cuDNN version: 10

GPU model: 1050 GTX

I can provide any files you ask, please help me. *In tensorflow's github they told me to ask in Stackoverflow...*

**Update:**

I got the problem solved thanks to the answer, here is the content of cvOut:

```
  [[[[-0.00476191 -0.00361736  0.          0.25361738 -0.07576995
     0.03405379  0.40910327]
   [ 0.21594621  0.04544836  0.          0.28788495  0.30689242
    -0.13025634  0.05074273]
   [ 0.46358964  0.19925728  0.         -0.09778295  0.26563603
     0.34778297 -0.02014329]
   [-0.01515752  0.3534766   0.          0.32857144 -0.00361736
     0.67142856  0.25361738]
   [ 0.25756338  0.03405379  0.          0.21594621  0.3787817
    -0.05689242  0.6212183 ]
   [ 0.30689242  0.203077    0.          0.796923    0.19925728
     0.40103063 -0.09778295]
   [ 0.5989694   0.34778297  0.         -0.01515752  0.68680996
     0.26515752  0.66190475]
   [-0.00361736  1.0047619   0.          0.59089667  0.03405379
     1.0757699   0.21594621]
   [ 0.712115   -0.05689242  0.          0.30689242  0.53641033
     0.05074273  1.1302563 ]
   [ 0.19925728  0.7343639   0.          0.93230265  0.34778297
     0.64652336 -0.01515752]
   [ 1.0201433   0.26515752  0.          0.24638264  0.33809522
     0.50361735 -0.07576995]
   [ 0.2840538   0.40910327  0.          0.04544836  0.19310758
     0.28788495  0.5568924 ]
   [-0.13025634  0.30074272  0.          0.44925728  0.06769729
     0.15221705  0.26563603]
   [ 0.59778297 -0.02014329  0.          0.3534766   0.5151575
     0.32857144  0.24638264]
   [ 0.67142856  0.50361735  0.          0.2840538   0.7424366
     0.4659462   0.3787817 ]
   [ 0.19310758  0.6212183   0.          0.203077    0.30074272
     0.796923    0.44925728]
   [ 0.40103063  0.15221705  0.          0.59778297  0.31319004
     0.23484248  0.68680996]
   [ 0.5151575   0.66190475  0.          1.0047619   0.50361735
     0.59089667  0.2840538 ]
   [ 1.0757699   0.4659462   0.          0.19310758  0.95455164
     0.5568924   0.53641033]
   [ 0.30074272  1.1302563   0.          0.7343639   0.15221705
     0.93230265  0.59778297]
   [ 0.64652336  0.23484248  0.          0.5151575  -0.00476191
     0.49638262  0.33809522]
   [ 0.75361735 -0.07576995  0.          0.40910327  0.7159462
     0.04544836  0.44310758]
   [ 0.28788495  0.8068924   0.          0.55074275  0.46358964
     0.69925725  0.06769729]
   [ 0.40221703  0.26563603  0.         -0.02014329  0.48484248
     0.3534766   0.7651575 ]
   [ 0.32857144  0.49638262  0.          0.75361735  0.25756338
     0.5340538   0.7424366 ]
   [ 0.7159462   0.3787817   0.          0.6212183   0.8068924
     0.203077    0.55074275]
   [ 0.796923    0.69925725  0.          0.40221703  0.5989694
     0.84778297  0.31319004]
   [ 0.48484248  0.68680996  0.          0.66190475  0.49638262
     1.0047619   0.75361735]
   [ 0.59089667  0.5340538   0.          0.7159462   0.712115
     0.44310758  0.95455164]
   [ 0.8068924   0.53641033  0.          1.1302563   0.69925725
     0.7343639   0.40221703]
   [ 0.93230265  0.84778297  0.          0.48484248  1.0201433
     0.7651575  -0.00476191]
   [ 0.74638265  0.33809522  0.         -0.07576995  0.7840538
     0.40910327  0.9659462 ]
   [ 0.04544836  0.6931076   0.          1.0568924  -0.13025634
     0.80074275  0.46358964]
   [ 0.94925725  0.06769729  0.          0.26563603  1.0977829
    -0.02014329  0.7348425 ]
   [ 0.3534766   1.0151576   0.          0.74638265  0.67142856
     1.0036174   0.25756338]
   [ 0.7840538   0.7424366   0.          0.3787817   0.6931076
     0.6212183   1.0568924 ]
   [ 0.203077    0.80074275  0.          0.94925725  0.40103063
     0.65221703  0.5989694 ]
   [ 1.0977829   0.31319004  0.          0.68680996  1.0151576
     0.66190475  0.74638265]
   [ 1.0047619   1.0036174   0.          0.7840538   1.0757699
     0.9659462   0.712115  ]
   [ 0.6931076   0.95455164  0.          0.53641033  0.80074275
     1.1302563   0.94925725]
   [ 0.7343639   0.65221703  0.          1.0977829   0.64652336
     0.7348425   1.0201433 ]
   [ 1.0151576   0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.1         0.2
     0.2         0.1       ]
   [ 0.1         0.2         0.          0.1         0.1
     0.2         0.2       ]
   [ 0.1         0.1         0.          0.2         0.1
     0.1         0.2       ]
   [ 0.2         0.1         0.          0.2         0.2
     0.1         0.1       ]
   [ 0.2         0.2         0.          0.8479438   0.67317617
     0.5581815   0.1778345 ]
   [-0.9215721   1.5896183   0.          0.6099795   0.5955366
    -0.46569395 -0.8461083 ]
   [ 1.6129647   1.4244858   0.          0.5209342   0.17585325
    -0.8687666   1.7872683 ]
   [ 1.3389692   0.8533131   0.         -0.00590521 -0.7195761
     1.6236191   1.1828533 ]
   [ 1.1838211   0.6728102   0.         -0.785988    1.2751837
     1.1616383   0.933811  ]
   [ 0.4684658   0.2719049   0.          1.2093123   0.66612804
     0.66964823  0.55971766]
   [ 0.17104894 -1.0688283   0.          0.6494252   0.6844874
     0.66586125  0.01329695]
   [-1.2607187  -0.22749203  0.         -0.8741171  -0.9443728
    -0.9659323  -0.03422031]
   [-0.0364061   0.54829746  0.          0.6263525   0.66758543
     0.04167109 -0.11780822]
   [ 0.48400337  0.4685324   0.         -0.04594427  0.02469592
    -0.3487326   0.08831279]
   [ 0.4161314   0.23332608  0.         -0.13553022 -0.31008872
     0.04969648  0.5674252 ]
   [ 0.36492363 -0.07475745  0.         -0.03859219  0.2016789
    -0.39845943 -0.07058203]
   [-0.08173721  0.1720942   0.          0.02323131  0.07122216
     0.07469177  0.12792486]
   [-0.24689877  0.196296    0.          0.5564647   0.535513
     0.22528338 -0.37152448]
   [-1.7235181  -1.8204601   0.         -1.5040898  -1.8099409
    -1.8550183  -1.1855855 ]
   [-1.6341007  -1.3448519   0.         -1.6656716  -1.6564709
    -1.2735447  -1.3357594 ]
   [-1.2829769  -1.2869868   0.         -1.6657944  -1.4066424
    -1.4230443  -1.4196167 ]
   [-1.3691044  -1.656098    0.         -1.4339573  -1.5685135
    -1.633306   -1.4437945 ]]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was caused by the wrong input `.pbtxt` file passed into the function `readNetFromTensorflow` because the `.pbtxt` has to be geneated by [`tf_text_graph_ssd.py`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_ssd.py) as describe [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/17ad33c9196aa75df24d4f1c1763547079f5b650/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_ssd.py#L359):

`Run this script to get a text graph of SSD model from TensorFlow Object Detection API. Then pass it with .pb file to cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow function.`

For other models such as [faster r-cnn](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_faster_rcnn.py) and [mask r-cnn](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_mask_rcnn.py), there are also corresponding scripts.

PS: I just found there is a very good official tutorial [here.](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API)

Comment: I think you are right I just tried that and no error was shown... but failed to detect... where should I include the label then? Thanks for help!!

Comment: I'm sure this could help, `https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/object_detection.py`

Comment: Ok thanks for the tutorial you just added. Now I see that I don't have to bother about the label, I checked the label_map_path file, I had the label misspelled, I restarted training... hope it works this time. Thanks!

Comment: After retraining for 3 days and getting 0.4 loss it fails to detect... I also tried the optimization method and nothing works... should I post another question? Or can you give me some guidance? Thanks!

Comment: You might start trying to figure out why the detection fails. For example, you can run the model to see if there is any output, in your case, what is the `cvOut` varible like?

Comment: I posted the content of `cvOut` in the question, I see some data there... I think it's a good thing... But when I draw score = 0 all image become full of lines...

Comment: I see one potential problem in your original code, `cols` and `rows` should be the original image size but not the size after `resize`, this may cause the final coordinates calculated wrong since the coordinates in the `cvOut` are normalized into [0,1]. But I also saw that the scores are all 0, which means no meaningful objects are detected, this would be very strange if the input image do contain the objects?

Comment: I tried removing resize and with color but with same result... indead i was able to detect object using lbp opencv but I am trying deep learning... I think the problem is not in code though... I will let it train furthermore...